# SwiftUI Preview error (process launch failed)

Tags: swift, swiftui

It seems that somehow i am screwing the SwiftUI Preview. When loading the simplest Preview like

```swift
struct MaterialView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

it crashes with following error:

> RemoteHumanReadableError: The operation couldn’t be completed. Transaction failed. Process failed to launch successfully. (process launch failed)
>
> BSTransactionError (1):
> ==transaction: <FBApplicationProcessLaunchTransaction: 0x6000012e01c0>
> ==error-description: Process failed to launch successfully.
> ==error-reason: process launch failed
> ==NSLocalizedFailureReason: Transaction failed. Process failed to launch successfully. (process launch failed)

I can't figure out what causes this issue since i can run my app in the simulator w/o any errors. I use XCode 12 Beta 4. Any ideas?

Comment: Still have the same issue. Can't get it running on my iPhone 13 Pro and MacBook Air M1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't fix the issue yesterday but on starting Xcode today it just worked again. It seems to be a bug in Xcode which will hopefully resolved when Xcode 12 is out of the Beta.

To fix the error try restarting Xcode (didn't help me yesterday, but do it anyway) and restarting your Mac.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, but in my case diagnostics showed: RemoteHumanReadableError

My fix was to quit Xcode (close window and quit from the menu or use CMD+Q).

Delete contents of:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

Comment: This worked for me. Restarting Xcode or restarting my computer did not work.

Comment: Worked for me on Xcode 15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

In the event that this helps out anyone else, I had multiple instances of the same project opened without realizing it. Preview started working correctly after I closed the others.

Xcode 15.0 beta 8

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the targets not being signed causes the problem. Configuring the target settings like the following address the problem.
[Xcode project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egHOW.png)

Hope it can help out those who still struggle with it.